# Cloudflare Workers regional names

Tags: geolocation, cloudflare

while using Workers, I have a switch/case to match `request.cf.region`.

I cannot find the list of 21 names that Cloudflare uses for the regions of Italy.
I created my own, here below.
Can anybody confirm the list I'm providing matches Cloudflare's names?

As a reference I'm using the names from the wikipedia "Economy of regions" section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regions_of_Italy
A first discrepancy I've found, Cloudflare defines 'Lazio' as 'Latium'.

I'm trying to find if there's other names that don't match the names from Wikipedia.
I share the list for public use and maintenance.

```
Basilicata
Calabria
Campania
Emilia-Romagna
Friuli-Venezia Giulia
Latium
Liguria
Lombardy
Marche
Molise
Piedmont
Apulia
Sardinia
Sicily
Tuscany
Trentino-Alto Adige/Südtirol
Umbria
Aosta Valley
Veneto
```

Comment: Hi! Would you be able to clarify which Cloudflare feature you are referring to here?

Comment: thanks Paolo, I re-edited the content, hopefully it's clearer

Answer (score 1):

`request.cf.region` represents the ISO 3166-2 name for the first level region associated with the IP address of the incoming request. This is documented [at this page](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/request)

[image: Documentation Screenshot for region parameter]

For localisation inconsistencies I'd recommend to reach out to Cloudflare Support to have it reviewed.

Comment: thanks Paolo, on the ISO website "Lazio" is never seen as "Latium":
https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:code:3166:IT 
There's no way to check all regions by myself. I'll write to Cloudflare Support

Comment: published: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/workers-request-cf-region-for-italian-regions-doesnt-fit-iso-3166/299485